# How to setup a mock mode for SignInManager<ApplicationUser> in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using .net core web application. I have an account controller on the following lines

```
[Authorize]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public AccountController(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
        ILogger<AccountController> logger)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        // code code
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        // code code
    }
    ....
```

I am trying to setup mock mode for my application, for rest of the services, api I am able to do so at the DI level, where I register mock implementations to the interfaces. But I have no clue how to go about for the signinmanager, can someone explain how to achieve this?

Edit - the idea of mock mode is that the application can run and work partially  without needing an actual database to connect to.